# weak closure of unitary group in $B(H)$

Tags: general-topology, operator-theory

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space with dim $H=\infty$ , and $\cal{U}$ be the group of all unitaries on $H$.

Show that the weak closure of $\cal{U}$ is a semigroup with respect to the multiplication.

I know that in general multiplication is not jointly weakly continuous, also for this problem I suppose $u,v\in \overline{\cal U}^{w}$ so there is $\{u_i\} , \{v_i\} \subset \cal U$ such that $u_i\to u$ (weakly) and $v_i\to v$ (weakly), but can not conclusion that $u_iv_i\to uv$.

Please help me. Thanks in advance